# How to use spellchecker plugin with tinymce 4.0.12

Tags: wicket, spell-checking, tinymce-4

I am using tinymce 4.0.12 in my wicket project. I have added spellchecker plugin in my editor,

but when i click on spell checker icon it gives ERROR: GENERAL, and the console error i'm getting is:

POST

```
http://localhost:1100/project/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/resources/wicket.contrib.tinymce.TinyMceBehavior/spellcheck_rpc 404
```

Note: I have added this code in my tinyMCE init function for spellchecker.

spellchecker_rpc_url :"resources/wicket.contrib.tinymce.TinyMceBehavior/spellcheck_rpc",

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE uses a remote spellchecking API to do the spellchecking for you. It seems that it used the Google API for spellchecking which got discontinued. It could also be the case that you have to manually configure the spellchecking engine used.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:spellchecker (This is for TinyMCE 3, but i guess it works similarly in TinyMCE 4)